# Terminal only reads first letter of file name

Tags: file, terminal, letter

This is not a question about coding, but the terminal. I have never had this problem before, but when I try to execute a script following by the file name to be executed, the terminal gives me the error message "no such file or directory 'a'" when the file name I entered is alphabet.txt. It does this regardless of the file, if I enter file beta.txt it can't find file or directory "b".

Has this happened to someone before?

Clarification: I have a python script, script.py, which takes a file as an argument, so I type: python script.py alphabet.txt
in the terminal and it gives me the error message "nos such file or directory 'a'"

Comment: You should show your python script as well

Comment: does that matter? I had no idea your script could affect how the terminal recognizes a file name. In that case, maybe it's something in the script..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was my script that was wrong, I was iterating over the letters of the file name as opposed to several files...